# In Android Google Map, how do I search address within specific city?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoding-api, city

I am developing an app which is having a search box for address search. I have tried to use below link but it's only for country specific results.

[A link for address search](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore%20505468&sensor=false&components=country:IN)

I want it to search only specific city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line for city search

```
&components=locality:ahmedabad
```

search address within specific city

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore%20505468&sensor=true&components=locality:ahmedabad

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

Give it an address and it will return the latitude and longitude to you. Hope this helps.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score -1):

Use GeoCoder

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;

 Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(Injector.INSTANCE.getApplicationComponent().applicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
                        "City name", 5);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"ADRESSE "+ addresses.get(0) +",LAT :" + addresses.get(0).getLatitude() +", LONG :" + addresses.get(0).getLongitude() );
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: this is simple search, not within specific city/country